# Stop access to file and folder directory from url using localhost in PHP

Tags: file, url, localhost, hide

I want stop user to accessing my file and folder like when you right click on image in any websit and inspect it you will find its  when you move courser on src='xyz' you will find current source:xyz; which move you to the image file.
In my case the problem is that the "current source" show me complete path like:

http://localhost/login-project/AdminLTE-master/Admin_Registration/upload_img/pic-1.png
of my file and when

when I remove pic-1.png it show me all files and folder in ../upload_img and same when I remove /upload_img/ it shows me all the file and folder in /admin_registration/

I hope you understand my question please help me to solve this.

[right click on image inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGUXL.jpg)

[show complete path of file in url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnCSW.jpg)

[show me all image and file after come one step back in url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ifpN.jpg)

**strong text**

Comment: Please don't add code or errors as images, text is preferable. See also how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

use htaccess to stop access to your folder or files over URL so show 404 error.